# how to create custom link in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

how can i create a custom link in shopify?

this link to a product category {{ product_type | link_to_type }}

the code looks like this

```
  {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
    {{ product_type | link_to_type }}
```

i want to add a "view more" link next to this link that points to the same link. is that possible?

i tried but they don't work.

```
{{ '(view more)' | link_to_product_type }}
{{ '(view more)' | link_to_type }}
{{ '(view more)' | link_to: types?q=product_type }}
{{ '(view more)' | link_to: 'types?q='product_type }}
{{ '(view more)' | link_to: types?q=type }}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by chaining on a `replace` (or `replace_first`) filter.

```
{% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
    {{ product_type | link_to_type | replace_first: '</a>', ' (view more)</a>' }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will generate something along the lines of:

```
<a href="/collections/types?q=Type1" title="Type1">Type1 (view more)</a>
<a href="/collections/types?q=Type2" title="Type2">Type2 (view more)</a>
```

You can change the `(view more)` section of the replace/replace_first to whatever you want, but make sure it ends with `</a>` to close the tag and keep the space before it so it doesn't come out as `Type1(view more)`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! It worked! This seems a bit hacky though lol but thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! One thing I have learned from developing Shopify themes is you have to be VERY creative to get the results you want. Anything is possible as long as you are willing to try to get things to work in a way they weren't intended to.